# Rust version of Arduino SoftwareSerial

Tags: rust, serial-port, usart, software-serial

Is there a Rust alternative to the Arduino library providing the SoftwareSerial type, which allows one to use any two regular pins to do serial communication instead of having to do it through hardware?

Comment: This maybe? https://docs.rs/bitbang-hal/latest/bitbang_hal/

Comment: It looks good, how would I use a baudrate of 9600 with that Timer struct?

Comment: There is an example here: https://github.com/sajattack/bitbang-hal/blob/master/examples/serial.rs

Comment: I am unable to port that to Arduino, too much of a noob for that.

Comment: Is there any update on this? because bitbang_hal uses such an old version of embedded_hal, I couldn't get bitbang_hal to work.